# Smallest current-controlled voltage source in an IC?

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, integrated-circuit

You can multiply a vector and a matrix by encoding the vector in voltages and the matrix values as conductances of variable resistors (using eg floating gate transistors or phase change memory). The resulting currents represent the product.

The problem, as I understand it, is that to multiply the result by another matrix, you need to put the output vector (currents) back into voltages.

I've seen this done with an ADC+DAC pair, but I imagine there is a simpler way. I've heard that there is a power vs area tradeoff, but I don't understand how/why.

What is the smallest way to convert a current to a voltage in an integrated circuit?

Edit to clarify: I'm wondering specifically about which methods would work well with modern fab processes

Comment: *What is the smallest way to convert a current to a voltage in an integrated circuit?* <-- a resistor does this.

Comment: The SNR of this process tends to be pretty bad, by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic analog "computer" if it could still be called that, would utilize simple op-amp circuits. To convert Amps to Volts only requires a resistor, though using the op-amp makes it efficient and expandable.  In reality you might actually use a higher value resistor (to reduce excessive heat in the resistor), then you would give the op-amp circuit gain. As shown the resistor would need to dissipate 1 Watt of heat.

The resistor on it's own really does the basic conversion per Ohm's Law, V = I R . The op-amp buffers the output and allows addition circuitry to follow.

As with many analog circuits to achieve true accuracy you would need to use highly accurate components or include a method to calibrate the circuit.
.

[image]

.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a basic VCCS for an analog computer like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmXpKr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The op-amp with R1 and M1 forms a voltage-controlled current sink. M2 and M3 are a current mirror to replicate M1's current in a source configuration.

Comment: It's no bigger than the other components you'd need for your proposed  matrix multiplier.  The op-amp is maybe 7-10 transistors. A lot smaller than an ADC + DAC.

Comment: This is voltage-to-current, but you asked for current-to-voltage...somehow I got my lines crossed (maybe thinking that all you need for current to voltage is a resistor, and from your question it seemed like you already knew that)